# Angular ui-calendar (FullCalendar) not binding to scope events

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

While using Angular & FullCalendar (via the [angular-ui-calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) project), I can't seem to make events binding work correctly.

When hard coding the events:

```
    $scope.events = [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2016-03-04'
        }
    ];
    $scope.eventSources = {
        events: $scope.events,
        color: '#999',
        textColor: 'black'
    };
```

Everything works fine.

However, since the page includes filters for events, I need to be able to modify them on the go. When doing so, nothing is being modified on the calendar.

I've tried many different ways and read both the angular-ui-calendar & the [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) documentation, but could not find any clues as to why the binding does not work out of the box.

When I do this (timeout is being used just to simplify the question, consider an Ajax request instead):

```
    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = {
        events: $scope.events,
        color: '#999',
        textColor: 'black'
    };
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.events = [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2016-03-04'
        }
      ];
   },1000);
```

Nothing is being added to the calendar.
I've tried invoking the refresh methods on the fullCalendar element using

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
//also tried - uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
//also tried - uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('render');
```

(`uiCalendarConfig` is injected to the controller correctly).

I also tried wrapping the code with `$scope.$apply()` but with no success.

I worked before with fullCalendar directly via the javascript/jQuery API and it worked fine, the angular-ui-calendar documentation states that "*The ui-calendar directive plays nicely with ng-model.*" but so far it's been nothing but pain.

My actual HTML tag is

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

There are no erros in the console whatsoever.

Any idea as to how to solve this and why the event binding is not a straight forward approach as one could assume?

Answer (score 1):

the events are bound during initalization of the calendar widget.
this is why your only chance if you want it to be updated on the fly, you will have to initialize the widget when you have all information you need to generate events, etc.
what you could do for example is putting your widget inside of an

```
<div ng-if="widgetConfigLoaded">...</div>
```

while setting widgetConfigLoaded to true after you set up your config

what you also could try, but probably won't work because of the thins i just said is instead of

```
$timeout(function() {
      $scope.events = [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2016-03-04'
        }
      ];
   },1000);
```

you can try

```
 $timeout(function() {
      $scope.events.push(
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2016-03-04'
        }
      );
   },1000);
```

because what you do is OVERWRITING the $scope.events with a new array. this new array has nothing to do with the $scope.events you linked to your config before. the config will still have an empty array inside.

to make it a bit clearer think about the following code:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;
a = [1,2,3];
```

what would you expect b to be ? it will be an empty array of course.

Comment: Thanks but that seems as a big caveat, are you saying there is no 'angular' way of modifying the events that are being displayed after initialization?

Comment: look at my edited post. if the second part won't help you then it's like that yeah. then angular-ui-calendar doesn't support binding events "later on". this happens quite often. it's simply a problem of the directive because it's not "implemented that way" then

Comment: I've already tried pushing the data to the `$scope.events`, doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Then it's not real binding

Comment: that has nothing to do with the binding itself. but i know what you mean. yeah its simply a passing of a config. the directive doesn't "have to" support changes of the config during runtime. sometimes thats not even possible, because it couldn't know on how to behave on changes of the config. it IS binded in a way that the config changes on the scope of the directive. but that doesn't mean that the directive has to react to those changes. its a question of implementation and definition

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like a terrible implementation of the ui-calendar, since if I wanted to be back in 2005 I could use jQuery not Angular. I think I found an answer using the `removeEvents` and `addEventSource` methods of the calendar, which allows re-inserting of data....hackish but it works.

Comment: plus 1 for pointing out that what I'm looking for does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do re-load the whole events rendering in order to apply new/updated/deleted events to the calendar.

```
    function formulateSources() {
        console.log('formulating sources',events);
        $scope.eventSources = [events];
        if(uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar) {
            uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are a bit closer.

```
$scope.events = [
    {
        title: 'Event1',
        start: '2016-03-04'
    }
];
```

Set this events in your calendars configuration.

```
events: $scope.events,
```

Comment: No any difference, just a different way to assign events.

Comment: Thanks but it won't solve the problem of post changes not showing on the calendar. I've found a work around using `removeEvents` and `addEventSource` every time the events are changed in real time.

Comment: Are you getting events from ajax?

Comment: Indeed, and also once loaded the events can be filtered out by the user so each change in the $events object need to be reflected in the calendar UI.

Comment: Then, you can use event function where you can make ajax call and set ajax response as events using callbalck function.

Comment: You can also manage switching user and user events by eventRender and rerenderEvents.